# Converting Boolean circuit to Boolean formula in parallel

Tags: parallel-computing, circuits

Let *t* be a fixed constant. I would like to convert a Boolean circuit *C* of depth *t* on *n* inputs over AND, OR and NOT gates (of fan-in 2, say) to an equivalent Boolean formula *F* on the same *n* inputs, in the sense that for each input vector *x* of length *n*, we have *C*(*x*) = 1 if and only if *F*(*x*) = 1. Some restrictions on the problem: the circuit has size *m* and depth *t*, and I would like the function mapping *C* to *F* to be computable by a PRAM (say) using a number of processors polynomial in *m* and time polylogarithmic in *m*. I don't mind that the size of the resulting formula is *O*(*m*<sup>*t*</sup>), I consider *t* to be a constant.

The approach I envision is to enumerate each path of length *t* from the output gate to each input gate and transform that set of paths into a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). This trie will then be a tree of branching factor *m* and depth *t* representing a Boolean formula of size *O*(*m*<sup>*t*</sup>), observing that this is a polynomial in *m* if I consider *t* to be a fixed constant. My problem then reduces to the problem of constructing a trie from a set of at most *m*<sup>*t*</sup> strings, each one a string of length at most *t* over an alphabet of cardinality *m*.

Can I construct a trie of strings of length *t* over an alphabet of size *m* in parallel time polylogarithmic in *m*? More generally, can I convert a Boolean circuit of size *m* and depth *t* to a Boolean formula in parallel time polylogarithmic in *m*?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [the Tseitin transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tseytin_transformation).  The Tseitin transform can be applied in parallel, working separately on each gate.  Consequently, this can be implemented using one processor per gate, $O(1)$ time per gate, and the resulting formula has size $O(m)$.  Here I'm not counting the time to build the final formula; the final formula is a conjunction of the clauses produced by the processors, with each processor adding $O(1)$ clauses to the final conjunction.

Comment: This will produce a formula with many more variables than input gates in the original circuit; I should have clarified that I expect the inputs to the circuit and the variables in the formula to be identical; I will update the question to clarify that.